# Using "$@" in bash function has different result than directly running command in bash

Tags: bash

When running `history` on the command line the results are like this:

```
$history aws s3 cp
16160  aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/air2008/10 .
16254  hists "aws s3 cp"
```

For a function `hists` that is intended to be a shortcut for the above:

```
type hists
hists is a function
hists ()
{
    history 15000 | grep "$@"
}
```

When running it we get

```
09:40:44/csv $hists aws s3 cp
grep: s3: No such file or directory
grep: cp: No such file or directory
```

If we run it with quotes then it does get correct result.  But then are quotes mandatory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$hists "aws s3 cp"` “expands” to `history 15000 | grep "aws s3 cp"`. This means `grep` receives a single argument.

`$hists aws s3 cp` expands to `history 15000 | grep "aws" "s3" "cp"`. `grep` receives three arguments.

The first argument to `grep` is the pattern. The other arguments are files that `grep` is to find the pattern in. There are no files called `s3` or `cp` in the current folder, so `grep` displays error messages.

Quotes can change the meaning of text on the command line. If you want an argument to contain whitespaces, quotes are one way to accomplish this.

`$hosts aws\ s3\ cp` does the same thing: By adding a backslash before the whitespace, the shell knows to not use the usual meaning, which is to separate arguments. Instead, it’ll become a literal whitespace.

There is also no difference in behavior with `"$@"`. It exists precisely to preserve quoted arguments.

Answer (score 1):

[The other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1460535/432690) is good. It explains what happened:

> `hists aws s3 cp` expands to `history 15000 | grep "aws" "s3" "cp"`. `grep` receives three arguments.
>
> The first argument to `grep` is the pattern. The other arguments are files that `grep` is to find the pattern in. There are no files called `s3` or `cp` in the current folder, so `grep` displays error messages.

My answer will allow you to ruggedize and modify the function so `hists aws s3 cp` will work.

---

First note `grep "$@"` in your original code allows you to inject *options* to `grep`, like this:

```
hists -i LS
```

You may or may not want to be able to do this. If not, the piece of code should be [`grep -- "$@"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618). But even then you will be able to pass filenames to `grep`. I expect you will never want `grep` in the function to operate on files. Some mechanism to prevent this would be useful.

If you'd like to be able to inject options, there's no trivial way to prevent you from specifying files as additional arguments. The function should pass multiple arguments to `grep`; it doesn't know by itself which one is an option, which one is a file. Some logic may deal with this, but let's keep things simple.

If you can live without injecting options to `grep`, you can make sure the tool gets just one argument, the pattern. You can use `grep -- "$1"`, but in this case

```
hists aws s3 cp
```

will be equivalent to `hists aws`, additional arguments won't matter. This is not exactly what you want but it will prevent `grep` from parsing `s3` and `cp` or throwing errors about them.

Or you can use `grep -- "$*"`. This is [what POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) about `"$*"`:

> When the expansion occurs in a context where field splitting will not be performed, the initial fields shall be joined to form a single field with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the `IFS` variable if `IFS` contains at least one character, or separated by a <space> if `IFS` is unset, or with no separation if `IFS` is set to a null string.

The inside of double-quotes is "a context where field splitting will not be performed" and the standard `IFS` begins with <space>. This means if you use `grep -- "$*"`, the command

```
hists aws s3 cp
```

will trigger `grep -- "aws s3 cp"`, which is what you wanted in the first place. Please note you will get the same result with

```
hists aws  s3           cp
```

despite multiple spaces. The point is `hists` doesn't see these spaces at all. It sees `aws`, `s3` and `cp` as separate arguments, then the mechanism of `"$*"` concatenates the three strings using single spaces.

On the other hand these commands:

```
hists "aws s3 cp"
hists "aws  s3           cp"
```

will work exactly as you would expect, regardless whether you use `grep -- "$*"` or `grep -- "$@"` or `grep -- "$1"`. The three variants behave differently when there are more arguments to `hists`; or less (try `hists` without any argument).

So with `grep -- "$*"` you can make the quotes optional in some cases. This variant will also prevent `grep` from parsing files, no matter what you type.